# Spring Boot. Doing a saveAndFlush with modifying an entity results to unsaved trancient exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a complex entity:

```
public class Task {
   @OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="parent")
   @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL) (org.hibernate.annotations ... package)
   private Executor executor;
...
}

public class Executor {
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn
   private Task parent;

   @ManyToOne
   @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Property> propList = new LinkedList<Property>();
}
```

Generally, it's a 'Task', which forms an 'Executor', and 'Executor' is filled in with some specific properties.

If I do this in a regular manner, meaning:

```
@Service
public class Service {
   @PostConstruct
   private void test() {
      Task task = new Task();
      Executor ex = new Executor();
      List<Property> props = ex.getProperties();
      ... forming and adding some properties
      taskDao.saveAndFlush(task);
   }
```

Everything is fine and the Task get's properly stored.

But since this is simplified, and I need to store the Task the moment I get one, meaning, right after the definition, and store it (flushing, no flushing, dividing into a separate method with transactioning),

```
@Service
public class Service {
   @PostConstruct
   private void test() {
      Task task = new Task();
      taskDao.saveAndFlush(task); // no change in the exception if I properly move this out to a separate method with @Transactional
      Executor ex = new Executor();
      List<Property> props = ex.getProperties();
      ... forming and adding some properties
      taskDao.saveAndFlush(task);
   }
```

I get the "unsaved transaction", which is pointing to the second "saveAndFlush".

And this is only achievable if I fill in the Properties, meaning that commenting out the "forming properties" part, everything is working well.

The cascade is ALL (the full list, held in org.hibernate.annotations...), so I'm having doubts for forgetting to specify "Cascade".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveAndflush` does not change the entity to managed state, you need to use managed entity returned by this method. Try this solution:

```
@PostConstruct
private void test() {
   Task task = new Task();
   task = taskDao.saveAndFlush(task);  // reassign
   Executor ex = new Executor();
   List<Property> props = ex.getProperties();
   ... forming and adding some properties
   taskDao.saveAndFlush(task);
}
```

Comment: The DB is MySQL, and the @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) doesn't cover "CascadeType.REMOVE", making it problematic to remove children by cascade.

Comment: Don't tell me I'm stuck in between the children removal and "all other" stuff :)

Comment: That's all that pops to my head, give it a try and I'll try to figure something out, that's better than this;)

Comment: Yes, this one I also tried a few times. Even did a overcompesating approach in saving, then fetching the saved Item by the formed Id, and then try it again (even with a separate method for save&return, which requested the entity by a formed Id.

Comment: Well, I just tried this on a different set of entities, and it appears that the problem somehow lies in the current entities that I'm using (which are a bit messy in terms on DDL).

Comment: Yes, once again the fault was the entity definition (the table behind the entity has been designed... randomly by someone). Had an incorrect definition in the Property definition related to the parent. Fixed it and all went well.